# ReactJS - Loading Indicator Not Disappearing

Tags: reactjs

I have a loading indicator that I want to appear when the page is loaded, but disappear once the component mounted. At first I tried to remove the indicator by using `this.setState(isLoading: false);` in the `componentDidMount(){}`, but that threw a warning. Instead I put this in `componentWillUnmount(){}` which makes the indicator visible, but once my components are loaded never disappears. Am I setting the state in the wrong place? Is there a better route to take?

I'm basically looking to hide `<LoadingIndicator/>` once `<BlogFeed/>` is present.

```
class BlogFeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {blogs: [], isLoading: true};
    }

    fetchList() {
....
}

componentWillUnmount(){
        this.setState(isLoading: false);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <LoadingIndicator loading={this.state.isLoading} />
                <BlogFeed {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }

//Loading Indicator
const LoadingIndicator = props => {
    if(props.loading){
        return (
            <div class="spinner">
              <div class="bounce1"></div>
              <div class="bounce2"></div>
              <div class="bounce3"></div>
              <p>Loading...</p>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState(isLoading: false);` is not valid JavaScript. Use [functional setState](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) instead:

```
this.setState(() => ({ isLoading: false }));
```

Comment: `this.setState({isLoading: false})` will be enough in this case. It's only necessary to use a function if the next state needs to be calculated based on the current state which may have been altered by a previous call of `setState()`. This is due to the fact that multiple calls to `setState()` are batched and would otherwise override previous calls.

Comment: Both methods are working for me, but your suggestion doesn't appear to remove the indicator once the `<BlogFeed />` component appears